# How to set the active status for a navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

I've tried multiple codes for setting an active status on a navbar menu link, but none of them works. Finally I found a bootply link that works: http://bootply.com/70331 , but it won't work on my menu. Here's my navbar:

```html
     <div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">

      <!-- .btn-navbar is used as the toggle for collapsed navbar content -->
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Be sure to leave the brand out there if you want it shown -->
      <a class="brand" href="{{ URL::to('news/index') }}">emiAAC</a>

      @include('common.menu_addition')
      @include('common.view_special')

      <!-- Everything you want hidden at 940px or less, place within here -->
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="{{ URL::to('news/index') }}"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i> News</a></li>
           <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-globe"></i> Community <b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="{{ URL::to('characters/search') }}">Characters</a></li>
               <li><a href="{{ URL::to('online') }}">Online list</a></li>
               <li><a href="{{ URL::to('highscores') }}">Highscores</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li class="nav-header">NOT DONE</li>
               <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Houses</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Guilds</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Guild Wars</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Live casts</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-book"></i> Library <b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li class="nav-header">NOT DONE</li>
               <li><a href="#">Exp. stages</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Monsters</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Quests</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Spells</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>
             <li class="dropdown">
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="icon-info-sign"></i> Help <b class="caret"></b></a>
             <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li class="nav-header">NOT DONE</li>
               <li><a href="#">Rules</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
             </ul>
          </li>


<form id="custom-search-form" class="form-search form-horizontal pull-right" action="{{ URL::action('CharactersController@search') }}" method="get">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="search-query" name="character" placeholder="Character/guild name">
        <button type="submit" class="btn"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>

      </div><!-- /.nav-collapse -->
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add the class `active` on your `<li>`. The link you provided use the HTML *active state* with the URL fragment (the part that follow the `#` symbol), in your case you to check the URL then add the `active` class to the current `<li>`.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo As far as I've done, it only works on one menu bar link. Maybe I've done it wrong, could you update and paste in the laravel paste site please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example for one of them

`<li class="{{ Request::is('characters/*'
) ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{ URL::to('characters/search') }}">Characters</a></li>`

Comment: I understand the most of it, but what is the Request::is function/method doing?

Comment: It just checks the URI.  The `*` acts as a wild card.  So if your URL looks like myapp.com/public/characters/<anything can go here>, that function would return true and give the class of 'active' to the element.

Comment: it works, but it doesn't remove. also, how could I set it in the class of a dropdown? and also, when I view a submenu (dropdown menu) I want it to make the main menu link active, not the submenu. could you transform it all to that code, I'm kind of confused.. lol

Comment: `<li class="{{ Request::is('highscores/*' ) ? 'active' : ''><a href="{{ URL::to('highscores') }}  }}">Highscores</a></li>` ??  I think you are making this more difficult than it needs to be.  Every time your page reloads, it's going to reset the classes.  If it's not removing it from characters, then you are still viewing something having to do with characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<li>{{ HTML::link('service/'.$user_id.'/'.$filename, 'Service') }}</li>
<li class="active">{{ HTML::link('#', 'Search') }}</li>
<li>{{ HTML::link('diff/'.$user_id.'/'.$filename, 'Compare') }}</li>
```

Comment: I don't understand you. What service and things? haha